# Eclipse, pydev and virtual environments

Tags: pydev

I have been searching for a good way to use python virtual environments from within eclipse.

The only suggestion I have found is to create a new eclipse-wide "interpreter" for each virtual environment. That is cumbersome for many project, but it works.

I want to have a virtual environment per project, so the path to the interpreter will have to change for each project.

1) can you define an interpreter specific for a project?

2) alternatively, how do you define an interpreter that use e.g. PROJECT_LOC variable?

any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way that PyDev works, it expects all interpreters to be configured "eclipse-wide" (and then in a given project you can say which one should be used for that particular project if it shouldn't be the default one).

The other option is actually having one Eclipse workspace per project (then you'd configure a single "eclipse-wide" interpreter for it).

Another option, if the interpreters are from the same Python version and you're only changing the installed libraries would be creating a single "eclipse-wide" interpreter as the default one for all projects and then configuring the additional paths to be included in the PYTHONPATH per project.

Personally what I usually do is having one Eclipse workspace per project and having everything independent as I'm usually working on a single project at a time (so, I can focus only on what it's important for it), so, switching projects would be opening a new Eclipse instance pointing to the proper place, although it depends quite a lot on your use case (which you haven't actually made explicit) -- each project would have its own virtual env configured "eclipse-wide" (although in my case it's actually conda virtual envs).

Comment: I was looking for the same feature. I am new to Python, but I was looking for some way to have a clean environment per project like I can do with Java in Eclipse using the M2E Maven plugin. I was thinking that PyDev would assist in creating a venv per project and then installing the dependencies via the latest packaging standards (pip, setup.py, requirements.txt, etc.). It looks like this is not currently in the feature set, but do you think this is a possibility in the future?  Do you know if other IDE's support this?

Comment: Since I shift back and forth between the command line and eclipse, maintaining the virtual environment is easier from the command line, and then it is simply to add "${PROJECT_LOC}/venv" to the PYTHONPATH.
This assumes that the virtual environment is in "venv" in the project folder - in my case that is the git repo folder.

Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @successhawk PyDev does support all that, although it expects you to use those tools and just interprets the result (i.e.: you're supposed to use `pip` or `conda` or `venv` or `your favorite tool` from the command line and inside PyDev just point to the interpreter created -- later on, if you install more things through the command line PyDev should understand those changes -- that wasn't always the case, but it should definitely work in the latest releases).